# Convergence Of Sequence Of Integers Without Using Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $\left ( x_{n} \right )_{n=1}^{∞}$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$. Show there is a $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_{0} = x_{n}$ for $n \geq n_{0}$. I realize that this answer was asked here: [Convergent sequences of integers are eventually constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187362/convergent-sequences-of-integers-are-eventually-constant) but the answer makes use of the Cauchy sequence which I have not learned yet. I've been stuck on this question for a while and can't seem to get anywhere with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is one of the many properties of the integers that depend on the fact that any two distinct integers differ by at least one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sequence converges, there must exist a limiting value $a\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. Now apply the definition of the limit with $\epsilon=\tfrac12$ to conclude that there is an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n-a|<\tfrac12$. Since $a_n,a$ are integers this implies that $a_n=a$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: One can't assume that limit $a$ is also an integer.

Comment: Yes you can, since that is what a "convergent sequence in $\mathbb Z$" means.