# Homeomorphism in discrete metric space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb N \subset\mathbb R$ be given the induced metric $d.$ Consider $\mathbb N$ with discrte metric $\delta$. How to show that $(\mathbb N,d)$ and $(\mathbb N,\delta)$ are homeomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that $id:(\Bbb N,d)\to (\Bbb N,\delta)$ is a homeomorphism.

It is clearly a bijection.

Also it is continuous since $id^{-1}(\{n\}) = \{n\}$ and this is open in $(\Bbb N,d)$ since $\{n\} = (n-1,n+1)\cap\Bbb N$.

Try now to show that this map is also open , and this conclude the proof.

Comment: Can we argue in the following way that, Every convergent sequence is cauchy. Hence all the convergent sequence in ($\mathbb N,d$) is constant sequence. On the other hand all constant sequences are convergent in ($\mathbb N,\delta$).Thus if we choose an identity map id:$(\mathbb N,d) \rightarrow (\mathbb N,\delta) $ is continuous?

Comment: i don't see why going this way, proving it is continuous is easy just using the definitions..

Comment: Thank you sir for answering the question. Is there any mistake in my way of interpreting? As i am a beginner, i was just trying to link concepts.

Comment: hmm. why "hence all convergent sequence in.. is constant" ?

Comment: Do you mean identity map by id?

Comment: yes, the identity map.

Comment: Please see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187362/convergent-sequences-of-integers-are-eventually-constant

Comment: So, you are showing that $id$ is sequentially continuous and this is indeed equivalent to continuity of $id$ since the spaces are first countable.

Answer (score 2):

In both metric, all singletons are open, and hence all subsets of $\mathbb N$ are open.

Hence, every function $f: (\mathbb N,d) \to (\mathbb N,\delta)$, which is one-to-one and onto (for example, the identity map), is continuous, as it inverts open sets, i.e., if $U$ is $\delta-$open, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is $d-$open. And so is its inverse.

Hence, every  bijection $f: (\mathbb N,d) \to (\mathbb N,\delta)$ is a homeomorphism!

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate why in $(\Bbb N,d)$ all singleton subsets are open? Is it because of the condition that Every convergent sequence is cauchy?

Comment: For all $n\in\mathbb N$, we have that $B_1(n)=\{n\}$, i.e., the open ball centred at $n$ with radius 1 is a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same set with the same topology: $\delta$ induces the discrete topology as all singletons are open: $\{n\}=B_\delta(n,1)$ and so all subsets are open (being unions of singletons).

The same holds for the metric $d$: $B_d(n,1)=(n-1,n+1) \cap \Bbb N = \{n\}$ as well, so again the discrete topology.

So any bijection on $\Bbb N$ (including the trivial one, the identity), is a homeomorphism, as any function on a discrete space is continuous.